# Pandas Iterate Through Selected Elements in List

Tags: loops, python-3.x, exception

Given the following list:

```
a = ['foo','bar','baz']
```

If I want to iterate through a and do something (i.e. print each element) for only some selected elements (or excluding an element), how would I go about doing that?

Here's the desired result:

```
['foo','bar']
```

or

```
['bar']
```

or

```
['bar','baz']
```

I've tried these (obviously not effective):

```
#For only printing the second element:
for i in a:
   print (i[1])
```

and

```
for i in a:
   if i[]==2:
   print (i)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: lambda, map - apart from that, it is not even clear what you want to do exactly. it seems (your for-loop) you want to iterate over the elements, but then you write, you only want to iterate selected elements...

Comment: Please see edits above for desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can do the following:

```
for i in a:
    if i==a[0]:
        print(i)
```

To get the first element of a, for example, in the loop.